# css&html nav bar should appear when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, nav, checked

I've tried using the two sibling selectors (`~`, as in snippet, and `+`) to make the `nav` bar appear when the box is checked, but it doesn't work, nor do I know what else to do.

```css
nav {
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#check:checked~nav {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check"><label for="check"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label></div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems to be working: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/ExjKyxP

Comment: hmm..weird. I have to admit I haven't used codepen first, but somehow, either VS Code or Chrome makes some kind of mistake when loading, bcz it doesn't work there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you code should look like, first you have a none closed `<div>` tag and for `+` sibling select move the label for the above the checkbox.

```css
nav{
    left: -100%;
    position: fixed;

}

#check:checked + nav{
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label for="check"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <nav>
    <ul><li><a href="">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

and if you want to have the same order for the tag change the `CSS` selector to this:

```css
nav{
    left: -100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#check:checked + label + nav{
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Alright! I will try it. About the div, I forgot to delete it before posting, so my bad. Thanks !