# My icon isnt showing and sldo my responsive menu not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, font-awesome

When I reduce the `@media {}`
The icon shows, but when I cover full with `{}` the icon does not show. And also my responsive menu doesn't show.

```css
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
}




nav {
background-color: orange;
height: 80px;
}

nav ul{
float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 80px;
margin: 0 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
position: relative;
color:white;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding: 5px 0;
}
nav ul li a:before {
position:absolute;
content: '';
left: 0;
height: 3px;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
transform:scaleX(0);
transform-origin: right;
background-color: white;
transition: transform .4s linear;
}
nav ul li a:hover:before{
transform: scaleX(1);
transform-origin: right;
}
label #btn,
label #cancel {
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
float: left;
line-height: 80px;
margin-left: 20px;
cursor:pointer;
display:none;
}
#check {
display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
ul {
position:fixed;
height: 100vh;
width: 70%;
background-color: orange;
text-align:left;
top: 80px;
left:-100%;
transition: all .4s;

li {
position:relative;
left: 65px;
}
nav ul li {
display:block;
margin:50px 0;
line-height: 30px;
}
label #btn {
display: block;
}
 nav ul li a {
 font-size: 16px;
 }
}

#check:checked ~ ul {
 left:0;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


  <nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label class="check" >
     <i class="fa fa-bars" id="btn" ></i>
     <i class="fa fa-times" id="cancel" ></i>
     </label>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Forums</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Vote</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

I want that when click on the icon, the menu shows but now the icon font even show. And also  when on bigger screens, like desktops, the text should show and the icon should not. But now it also isn't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey one error I've noticed is you are missing a closing bracket after your ul and that is why your icon is not showing. Moreover u need an onClick to display the the navbar as a hamburger menu.

just check this once u put the closing tag it displays the icon again.

Edit:

you can make the navbar responsive like this:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
 
</head>
<body>

  <nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
     </a>
     <i class="fa fa-times" id="cancel" ></i>
     <div id="myLinks">
          <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Forums</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Vote</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Contact us</a></li>
         
      </div>
      
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS: (change the media)

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  #myLinks {
    display: none;
  } 

  li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: left;
    top: 80px;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

 #btn {
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffff;
  }

/* #check:checked + ul {
  left: 0;
} */
}
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  var cancelBtn= document.getElementById("cancel");
  //console.log(x)
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

You can fix the css according to your preference

Comment: Oh thanks now its working but the menu is not working like it's not coming

Comment: That is because u dont have an onClick on the icon. So even if it is clicked there is no functionality added to it.

Comment: Don't the #check:checked ~ up { left: 0; }will work the video I'm seeing did this and it worked

Comment: And also the  text don't show on desktop it show the icon on desktop too

Comment: can u attach a jsfiddle or show the complete code? I am unable to grasp what the problem is..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60242759/csshtml-nav-bar-should-appear-when-checkbox-is-checked check out this link to have some clarity on the checked button